# How to synchronize Mediaplayer with phone volume?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I noticed that regardless of the volume I set my phone, the sound for a button click in my app remains the same regardless, how can I synchronize it with the phone's system volume? Here's the code format I used

```
Mediaplayer buttonSoundClick;

buttonClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click_sound);

buttonClickSound.start();



    buttonClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click_sound);
} private void prepareAsync() {

    buttonClickSound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//Button Click Sound
        buttonClickSound.start();
```

Comment: what Audio Stream Type are you using?

Comment: @pskink i'm sorry but I don't know what that means. Where can I find this information?

Comment: in MediaPlayer API docs?

Comment: @pskink I don't know how to answer his question. How can I find out the Audio Stream Type I am using? I posted the only code in relation to the Mediaplayer

Comment: ok so it seems you are using default Audio Stream Type, if the default is not what you want, then set Audio Stream Type that you would like to use

Comment: @pskink how do I do that?

Comment: did you try to see MediaPlayer API docs?

Comment: @pskink yes, but at my level, I still find it hard to understand API's

Comment: open the MediaPlayer javadoc page, type ^F setAudioStreamType and read every paragraph where that search phrase occurs, read carefully, don't miss any paragraph,  don't try to be too fast...

Answer (score 0):

Android has different volume levels for different stream types.

Override `onKeyDown()` and add the following code.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

After this, try playing around with the stream types to get it right for your app. The stream types available are:

```
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
AudioManager.STREAM_RING
AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM
AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM
AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION
```

**OR**

You could directly set the MediaPlayer stream type by using `MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)`

Buy, you must call this method before `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` in order for the target stream type to become effective thereafter.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but after playing around with it, the buttonClickSound ignore my phones volume level, how do  sync them together.

Comment: @ThatThatson you're calling `setAudioStreamType()` at the wrong position. Call it like this: `buttonClickSound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` *before* you call `buttonClickSound.start();`

Comment: @ThatThatson Did you try it?

Comment: @jazdez I didn't get it right. I'll just try it later when my general knowledge of android has increased.